# AWK: parsing arguments in a loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to write a simple script that will display the fields specified by the user as bash arguments. For example I've got text file looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e
```

And for example user types:

```
./script.sh text 1 2 5
```

Where $1 = text, and other parameters (like $2 $3 and $4) are the fields, so output will look like this:

```
1 2 5
1 2 5
a b e
```

I've got this code which prints all the columns defined as a arguments, but one below the others:

```
#!/bin/bash

text="$1"
shift

for x in $@; do
awk '{print $var}' var="$x" $text
done
```

Output for example ./script.sh text 1 2 5:

```
1
1
a
2
2
b
5
5
e
```

I guess output looks like that because loop "for" is outside of AWK. Is it a good solution for this task to place the loop inside AWK? I tried a few things but always have trouble with the syntax.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the params, pass all of them to `awk` with `-v` option:

```
awk -v v1=$2 -v v2=$3 -v v3=$4 '{print $v1, $v2, $v3;}' $1
```

You may want to perform additional checks such as whether the file (`$1`) contains enough fields, the file (`$1`) exists etc. But the idea is the same.

In your code, you are reading the file multiple times, each checking for only a particular field but to get your desired output, each line must be checked for multiple fields at the same time.

---

Pass the columns to awk and split them into an array and print the column corresponding to each value in the array:

```
file=$1
shift
p="$@"
awk -v l="$p" '{t=split(l,a," "); for (i=1;i<=t;i++) printf $(a[i]) " ";printf "\n";}' $file
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I've tried similar solution but it does not work if user types only 1 or 2 or simply 6 parameters. It's work only for 3 parameters and I want it to be "flexible".

Comment: You could pass all column numbers to `awk` to use an array and then print those columns.

Comment: Wow! Yeah, it's really works. Thank you for your help, now I have to understand this :).

Comment: Right idea with the 2nd script but: No need to specify the default FS as a 3rd arg for split(), its inefficient to do split() for every input line, never use `printf $N` use `printf "%s", $N` instead in case the input contains eg `%s`, no need to explicitly print the ORS, this will add a spurious trailing blank to every output line, no need to hard-code the default OFS value when printing the fields, no need for the trailing semi-colon, and never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
file="$1"
shift
awk -v flds="$*" 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try analyze both answers :).

Comment: You should leave BlueMoons answer checked as accepted because he had the right idea but you should use mine in your actual code.